# Combining INDEX/MATCH with COUNTIF

Tags: excel, count, indexing, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I'm working on a sensitive Excel file where I'm not allowed any VBA code, so I have to help myself with basic formulas in Excel. Please note that I am not allowed to add extra columns and the solution has to be in one single cell. What I have are two columns:

Column A has numbers from 1-10.
Column B has numbers from 1-10.

I'd like to know e.g. ***for all 3's in A, how many 5's are in B.***

The result would be as well seen with the use of two filters, but I don't want to do this over and over again, since the size of the columns will only get bigger.

I tried to use INDEX-MATCH command in the COUNTIF, but it's not that simple. The main problem is to define how to look and search in each row and then count/sum/whatever.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Works. Thanks! I'm a little bit ashamed cause of this. Such a simple solution and i tried with index.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though a function not available in versions of Excel before 2007, it seems:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,3,B:B,5)
```

met the requirement here.